# Discord Bot Java (Maven) Library not found, loading failed (com.sedmelluq / lavaplayer)

Tags: java, maven, bots, discord, lavaplayer

I programmed a Discord bot with Java (Eclipse). If I start it via console in Eclipse, it works without problems. If I export it as a "Runnable JAR file" and start it with the start.bat file, it also works fine.

start.bat:

```
java -jar NameOfTheFile.jar
pause
```

However, I don't want to keep my computer switched on permanently. A friend would have no problem with this, so the bot runs on his computer.
If the bot is started by the start.bat file, there is no error message and it works. However, if music is to be played (triggered via the bot in a voice channel by !play ), the error occurs that the library (needed to play the music) was not found ...

- I have Windows 10 + openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
- the friend's PC has Windows 7 + latest Java version

The error (short version):

```
[lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1] INFO com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader - Native library libmpg123-0: loading with filter com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.ConnectorNativeLibLoader$$Lambda$185/29224482@159940e
[lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1] ERROR com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader - Native library {}: loading failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Required library was not found
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.extractLibraryFromResources(NativeLibraryLoader.java:128)
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.loadInternal(NativeLibraryLoader.java:113)
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.loadAndRemember(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85)
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:70)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.ConnectorNativeLibLoader.loadConnectorLibrary(ConnectorNativeLibLoader.java:21)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.getInstance(OpusDecoderLibrary.java:14)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoder.<init>(OpusDecoder.java:20)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.initialiseDecoder(OpusPacketRouter.java:194)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.checkDecoderNecessity(OpusPacketRouter.java:178)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.process(OpusPacketRouter.java:94)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.consume(MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.java:47)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.processFrameInBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:372)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseClusterSimpleBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:336)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseNextCluster(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:321)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.provideFrames(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:297)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.lambda$process$0(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:40)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:276)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:250)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.process(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:39)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.DelegatedAudioTrack.processDelegate(DelegatedAudioTrack.java:25)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.processStatic(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:57)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.process(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:49)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:105)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$executeTrack$1(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:349)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1] INFO com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader - Native library connector: loading with filter null
[lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1] ERROR com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader - Native library {}: loading failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Required library was not found
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.extractLibraryFromResources(NativeLibraryLoader.java:128)
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.loadInternal(NativeLibraryLoader.java:113)
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.loadAndRemember(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85)
        at com.sedmelluq.lava.common.natives.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:70)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.ConnectorNativeLibLoader.loadConnectorLibrary(ConnectorNativeLibLoader.java:21)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.getInstance(OpusDecoderLibrary.java:14)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoder.<init>(OpusDecoder.java:20)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.initialiseDecoder(OpusPacketRouter.java:194)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.checkDecoderNecessity(OpusPacketRouter.java:178)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.process(OpusPacketRouter.java:94)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.consume(MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.java:47)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.processFrameInBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:372)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseClusterSimpleBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:336)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseNextCluster(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:321)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.provideFrames(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:297)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.lambda$process$0(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:40)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:276)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:250)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.process(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:39)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.DelegatedAudioTrack.processDelegate(DelegatedAudioTrack.java:25)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.processStatic(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:57)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.process(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:49)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:105)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$executeTrack$1(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:349)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1] ERROR com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor - Error in playback of Kh2FRFhS7QY
com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.FriendlyException: Something broke when playing the track.
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.ExceptionTools.wrapUnfriendlyExceptions(ExceptionTools.java:43)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:117)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$executeTrack$1(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:349)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.create(II)J
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.create(Native Method)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoder.<init>(OpusDecoder.java:21)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.initialiseDecoder(OpusPacketRouter.java:194)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.checkDecoderNecessity(OpusPacketRouter.java:178)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.process(OpusPacketRouter.java:94)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.consume(MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.java:47)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.processFrameInBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:372)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseClusterSimpleBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:336)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseNextCluster(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:321)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.provideFrames(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:297)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.lambda$process$0(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:40)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:276)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:250)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.process(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:39)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.DelegatedAudioTrack.processDelegate(DelegatedAudioTrack.java:25)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.processStatic(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:57)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.process(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:49)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:105)
        ... 4 more
Exception in thread "lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.create(II)J
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.create(Native Method)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoder.<init>(OpusDecoder.java:21)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.initialiseDecoder(OpusPacketRouter.java:194)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.checkDecoderNecessity(OpusPacketRouter.java:178)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.process(OpusPacketRouter.java:94)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.consume(MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.java:47)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.processFrameInBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:372)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseClusterSimpleBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:336)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseNextCluster(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:321)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.provideFrames(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:297)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.lambda$process$0(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:40)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:276)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:250)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.process(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:39)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.DelegatedAudioTrack.processDelegate(DelegatedAudioTrack.java:25)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.processStatic(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:57)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.process(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:49)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:105)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$executeTrack$1(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:349)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can attach the pom.xml if necessary.
com.sedmelluq or lavaplayer is added by the following depency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
  <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.50</version>
</dependency>
```

Why everything work for me and not on the other PC? Can someone please help? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my friend's computer had a 32 bit system and the music library probably only runs on 64 bit systems.